Possible research topics for a beginner in Topological QFT?
I am highly interested in Topological Quantum Field Theory (TQFT) and am currently planning on doing a project on this topic this year. Some relevant background: Algebra (Groups, Rings, Fields, basics of Categories and Modules), Topology (Munkres), Smooth Manifolds (John Lee's book, first 17 chapters - up to integration on manifolds and basics of deRham Cohomology), 2 semesters of undergrad Analysis and finally some intro algebraic topology (though I'll be officially studying this in the Fall). For physics, I'm currently starting to learn QFT from Peskin-Schroeder's popular book.
Now, TQFT recently has been developing rapidly and turned into a vast subject for a newcomer like me to find a specific topic to work on. I'm interested in aspects of TQFT concerning Category theory, knot theory, quantum groups and the likes. I'm also interested in existence of smooth structures. My understanding is that each one of these are themselves vast enough.
So, my question is:

What are some TQFT research topics a beginning grad student can pursue that relates to higher categories and/or knot theory? Can someone suggest some possible sub-topics to look at? Also, what "extra" background is needed?

Feel free to suggest if there are other sub-topics that are more suited for a beginner in the field. Ultimately, I want to get a feel for actual research in TQFT through a project. TIA.

you really need an expert advisor for this, do you have one?

@CarloBeenakker : Unfortunately, I don't have one and I don't know anyone personally who does TQFT. However, I still want to pursue this subject and do a project on it. This is why I'm posting this here to maybe get some directions to some topics.

Why the downvote? I've only posted this here to get some ideas of research topics in TQFT. If it was so simple to just email people working in the field or finding an advisor working in this area then I wouldn't be posting here! I have tried many times in the past to email people but never got any good replies.

Requests for personal advice are off-topic. And you aren't going to get useful advice for two reasons: 1. only someone who actually knows you (your background, your strengths/weaknesses, etc) can advise you on research topics; and 2. there are not an infinite supply of good problems for beginning graduate students (=doable with less background, of interest to a reasonable number of people, but not so well known that many other people are working on them), so someone who has enough experience to advise people will save them for their own students and not just post them on the internet.

(indeed, posting on the internet makes them less useful since then it is far more likely that a potential student will get scooped).

@AndyPutman : So what is someone supposed to do even do who doesn't have the luxury of having a mentor? Not everyone comes from the same academic environment filled with people willing to help. Is there any advice for someone who doesn't have any access to advisors?

If everyone in the field is keeping the "suitable questions" to themselves, then how do we expect the young community who doesn't have any access to these good advisors/good programs proceed with special areas of math/physics? There seems to be very little progress a newcomer in these areas of math can make without any access to these priviledges.

Aside from some very rare exceptional cases, I don't think it's possible to become a researcher in any area of mathematics without ongoing in-person mentorship.

@AndyPutman : Yes, this is the realization I'm having recently. But then what is to be done if one cannot find a mentor? Is there any general advice to proceed for someone like that? I really and absolutely love theoretical math & physics. But the only reason I could still not get an actual feel for research in these areas is the lack of a proper mentor. Seems like the types of areas I'm interested in are only available in "good" schools and when I try to reach out faculties of these schools, they are usually very busy to reply or mentor someone "unknown".

There is no alternate path, and I don't think that emailing random people to ask for mentorship is likely to give the results you want.  Professor are typically way to overwhelmed with responsibilities to offer on-going mentorship to people who email them (e.g., I have 5 PhD students at the moment + a huge amount of administrative work).  My only advice is to be more flexible about research areas, and to take advantage of what is available to you rather than remain frustrated about what isn't.

@AndyPutman : I hear you. But see, I came into mathematics because I liked doing mathematics. And in mathematics there are certain areas that definitely make me happier to work on than others. Just because the "system" is unable to help me doesn't mean I'll leave the things I like and start doing something that doesn't even keep me "happy". Changing into a related area is surely an option. But a completely different area should NOT be the only option left for anyone.I think this is not a problem on an individual level but a community level. Even more so in the US than some other countries.

@math-physicist: The system isn't different in e.g. Europe. I also don't think that this is something that is unique to academia or mathematics. It is a sad fact that not everyone gets to pursue their dreams. My grandfather was the first in the family to complete high school, and though he managed to go to Michigan Tech for a couple of years he was forced to drop out during the Great Depression and spend the rest of his life doing blue-collar work. You have two options in this life: take advantage of what is available to you (whatever that is), or be unhappy. There is no option three.

@AndyPutman:I understand what you say. For me my third option in this case is to keep on working my way through TQFT and eventually publish impactful articles. I don't believe that I should just stop doing it just because no one wants to help. I also don't believe that someone cannot become a mathematician without such help. My compromise would probably be doing it parallel to other areas that are available to me atm. For me stopping to do it would be giving up, which is never going to be an option. This is just my personal way of doing something. Anyways thanks for the discussion!

Speaking as someone who dropped out as an undergrad (second semester junior year) and is now arguably 'doing research', my advice would be to just pursue it like hell. Forgo sleep, social interaction, other pursuits, and whatever else you need to throw into the flames to make them burn bright enough to shed some real light. Warning: I had a full mental breakdown culminating in a week in  the mental ward of a hospital in New Mexico after about two years of this approach. But I survived, and it appears to have 'worked'. Best of luck from a fellow traveler.
